# asp.net build success but publish failed with System.OutOfMemoryException error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, publish

I managed to build the app but when trying to publish (publish method = file system), it hit the error at below. Sometimes I managed to publish but most of the times will fail with this error.
Can someone pls help in this issue?

Below are the methods that i have tried but did not work: -

1. run VS as administrator.
2. publish to new folder.
3. clean and rebuild and publish.
4. delete publish profile and create a new profile.

Output message:

```
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source.
2>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p C:\DevApps\MyService\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source -u -c C:\DevApps\MyService\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir 
2>/global.asax(1,0): Error ASPPARSE: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

p/s: i found a similar post with this error in this forum but it is publishing to Azure which is different from mine, i publish to local file system.

**Web.config file content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connstr" connectionString="EsAhekghcHDzZG3vSKGDfNbSRCTFE9NtzZqBKh/h54PqVjTpH8izjP+QkCuXQSYublNvOxcR0bEwQLW9IUlH/w==" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.7.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,              PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="false" name="authCookieDBD" timeout="1" path="/" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Drawing.Common" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.42.0.0" newVersion="1.42.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.42.0.0" newVersion="1.42.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Core" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.42.0.0" newVersion="1.42.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Api.Gax" publicKeyToken="3ec5ea7f18953e47" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Interactive.Async" publicKeyToken="94bc3704cddfc263" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="BouncyCastle.Crypto" publicKeyToken="0e99375e54769942" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.9.0" newVersion="1.8.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';style-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:; img-src 'self' https:;font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:" />
        <!--<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'unsafe-inline'"/>-->
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you add ASP.Net tags? Give us some information about the code or operation you posted? How big is your document to be released?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT the project folder is 4.19 GB. i checked the published folder is 541 MB (414 files, 37 folders).

Comment: As you said you can build it. Did you try to run it? Will this error occur during runtime?

Comment: Yes, can build can run, no error during runtime. it happened when publishing only.

Comment: Can you paste the code for the release configuration file? The solution seems to have entered a bottleneck, please give me more information.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I have added the web.config file content by editing at the post. pls have a look. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use the 64 bit visual studio if available for you.
2. Check the memory availability in your destination folder where you are targeting to publishing.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, what do you mean by using 64 bit VS? i checked my VS exe, it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE. I can't find any in Program Files folder. 

The destination folder is actually still at the same computer that i use to compile and publish. i set the publish as file system (C:\DevApps\Publish). My computer is having 32gb RAM, when i do publishing, the usage of memory is less than half of the memory.

Comment: Hi Angie Chuah, 32gb RAM for VS 2019 is sufficient for publishing, have you verified the available space in that drive? Can you check "C:\DevApps\Publish" is not shared folder just for sanity.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, still have 37GB in the C drive and it is not shared folder.

Comment: Hi Angie Chuah, Try to restart your VS because might be background and some process might be using. We see this kind of issue gone once we restart.

Comment: actually i did restart VS few times yesterday but could not publish it. now i tried again, can publish!!! well, then i tried few more times, all failed again... i am really not sure what is going wrong, it can publish some times but most of the times will fail...

Comment: can you try this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which process causing issue so that you can take the decision

Comment: Hi Rajesh, could you pls share with me on how to identify the process that may cause issue? i launched the process monitor, it shows a long list of process. i'm so sorry that i have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update that fixed the same issue for me...

When publishing i noticed aspnet_compiler.exe was using the 32 bit version instead of the 64 bit version in the build output.

32 bit compiler
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p ...

should read for 64 bit compiler
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe-v / -p ...

To fix this i added the following into my publish profile...
<AspnetCompilerPath>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319</AspnetCompilerPath>

Hope this helps somebody